# Nservicebus receive only endpoint - Prevent creation of topics and queues

Tags: nservicebus

I have  a receive only endpoint as a azure worker role listening to topics on ASB transport. This receive only endpoint is automatically creating receiveonlyendpoint.queue, receiveonlyendpoint.topic etc which i dont want. I just need a subscription to publisher.events and auto subscription works fine. How to control this in NServicebus 6 and NSB Asb transport 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ASB transport version 7 you need to choose the topology. [Documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-service-bus/topologies/) on topologies goes into details how those operate.

Note that endpoint is either a normal endpoint (sends and receives) and send only (doesn't receive). There's no receive only type. Therefore your endpoint is a full endpoint and will create necessary queues.